# Why is the LaTeXDraw logo so big in Xfce 4.10?

Tags: xfce, latex

Is there a bug in XFCE desktop? Namely, I can see some weird "XD"-letters when I try to open LaTeXDraw. Letters seem to be much bigger than the normal logo. It does not affect my mouse. I'm using Xfce 4.10, Ubuntu 12.10 and LaTeXDraw version 2.0.8, build 20100314.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: How did you install LaTeXDraw? Did you create your own menu item (desktop launcher). I add a similar problem (using Unity) with a custom launcher because its icon entry pointed to the actual icon instead of an icon in the icon theme.

Comment: @iBelieve I installed it via Synaptic. I had some problems with my hard disk and I had to reinstall system. Now I'm using Lubuntu but it seems that the LaTeXDraw logo is still bigger than other logos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be a bug in the desktop launcher for LaTeXDraw.

Copy the application icon to `~/.local/share/icons`:

```
cp /usr/share/pixmaps/latexdraw32.xpm ~/.local/share/icons/latexdraw.xpm
```

In the application launcher (`/usr/share/applications/latexdraw.desktop`), the icon entry is

```
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/latexdraw32.xpm
```

Replace this with

```
Icon=latexdraw
```

This should fix the problem!